# Clockify api to get all attendence data

Tags: postman, clockify

I am putting this url in postman: `https://reports.api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/reports/summary` to get summary reports but instead of any response I am getting nothing, no error either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can possibly share a curl request here for other ppl to debug.

Comment: I'am getting 400 bad request although I'am passing api-key in header and my workspace id is also correct

Comment: I was putting workspace id inside curly braces, but after that it is asking for summary filter how to pass summary filter?